# SPF hosted on CENT OS. Does not restarting the "named" service after editing the SPF record break the whole DNS File?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, spf

We had to change and Include entry from: `Include:Domain-name.com`
to: `Include:_Domain-name.com`

This was the only change we made. After a couple days none of our hosted resources were available.

My only thought is that it's because I didn't restart the named service after making the change. Can that break the DNS record by not doing so?

Here are the Logs:

error log beginning portion:

```
Dec 19 11:50:50 dns1 named[19971]: client 198.108.192.2#17490: RFC 1918 response from Internet for 39.40.18.172.in-addr.arpa
Dec 19 11:51:47 dns1 named[19971]: client 174.230.12.148#1961: update 'ncmich.edu/IN' denied
Dec 19 11:52:09 dns1 init: tty (/dev/tty2) main process (1994) killed by TERM signal
Dec 19 11:52:09 dns1 init: tty (/dev/tty3) main process (1996) killed by TERM signal
Dec 19 11:52:09 dns1 init: tty (/dev/tty4) main process (1998) killed by TERM signal
Dec 19 11:52:09 dns1 init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process (2000) killed by TERM signal
Dec 19 11:52:09 dns1 init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (2002) killed by TERM signal
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 abrtd: UnRegistered Analyzer plugin CCpp
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 abrtd: UnRegistered Analyzer plugin Kerneloops
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 abrtd: UnRegistered Action plugin KerneloopsScanner
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 abrtd: UnRegistered Reporter plugin Logger
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 abrtd: UnRegistered Analyzer plugin Python
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 abrtd: UnRegistered Reporter plugin RHTSupport
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 abrtd: UnRegistered Action plugin SOSreport
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 abrtd: UnRegistered Database plugin SQLite3
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 abrtd: Got signal 15, exiting
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 kernel: Removing vmci device
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 kernel: Resetting vmci device
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 kernel: Unregistered vmci device.
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 kernel: vmci 0000:00:07.7: PCI INT A disabled
Dec 19 11:52:10 dns1 xinetd[1688]: Exiting...
Dec 19 11:52:13 dns1 acpid: exiting
Dec 19 11:52:13 dns1 ntpd[1696]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Dec 19 11:52:13 dns1 named[19971]: received control channel command 'stop'
Dec 19 11:52:13 dns1 named[19971]: shutting down: flushing changes
Dec 19 11:52:13 dns1 named[19971]: stopping command channel on 127.0.0.1#953
Dec 19 11:52:13 dns1 named[19971]: stopping command channel on ::1#953
Dec 19 11:52:13 dns1 named[19971]: no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53
Dec 19 11:52:13 dns1 named[19971]: no longer listening on 198.108.192.70#53
Dec 19 11:52:13 dns1 named[19971]: exiting
Dec 19 11:52:16 dns1 init: Disconnected from system bus
Dec 19 11:52:16 dns1 console-kit-daemon[2043]: WARNING: no sender#012
Dec 19 11:52:16 dns1 rpcbind: rpcbind terminating on signal. Restart with "rpcbind -w"
Dec 19 11:52:16 dns1 auditd[2021]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Dec 19 11:52:16 dns1 kernel: type=1305 audit(1576774336.150:325449): audit_pid=0 old=2021 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
Dec 19 11:52:16 dns1 kernel: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
Dec 19 11:52:16 dns1 kernel: sit0: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Dec 19 11:52:16 dns1 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Dec 19 11:52:16 dns1 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.2" x-pid="1344" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Dec 19 11:52:37 dns1 kernel: imklog 4.6.2, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Dec 19 11:52:37 dns1 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.2" x-pid="1332" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
Dec 19 11:52:37 dns1 kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec 19 11:52:37 dns1 kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec 19 11:52:37 dns1 kernel: Linux version 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b6.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri May 20 03:51:51 BST 2011
Dec 19 11:52:37 dns1 kernel: Command line: ro root=UUID=72e41af2-547a-4424-934e-a60f7fbefb71 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us 
crashkernel=128M rhgb quiet
```

This is the end portion of the log, No more logs until we restored the old file on the 26th:

```
Dec 19 11:53:24 dns1 avahi-daemon[1535]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Dec 19 11:53:24 dns1 avahi-daemon[1535]: Registering new address record for fe80::250:56ff:fe9f:6be7 on eth0.*.
Dec 19 11:53:24 dns1 avahi-daemon[1535]: Registering new address record for 198.108.192.70 on eth0.IPv4.
Dec 19 11:53:24 dns1 avahi-daemon[1535]: Registering HINFO record with values 'X86_64'/'LINUX'.
Dec 19 11:53:24 dns1 acpid: starting up
Dec 19 11:53:24 dns1 acpid: 1 rule loaded
Dec 19 11:53:24 dns1 acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
Dec 19 11:53:25 dns1 avahi-daemon[1535]: Server startup complete. Host name is dns1.local. Local service cookie is 3246639356.
Dec 19 11:53:25 dns1 acpid: client connected from 1631[68:68]
Dec 19 11:53:25 dns1 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Dec 19 11:53:26 dns1 avahi-daemon[1535]: Service "dns1" (/services/ssh.service) successfully established.
Dec 19 11:53:26 dns1 automount[1650]: lookup_read_master: lookup(nisplus): couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1688]: ntpd 4.2.4p8@1.1612-o Wed Aug 25 13:54:50 UTC 2010 (1)
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: precision = 0.060 usec
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: Listening on interface #0 wildcard, 0.0.0.0#123 Disabled
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: Listening on interface #1 wildcard, ::#123 Disabled
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: Listening on interface #2 lo, ::1#123 Enabled
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: Listening on interface #3 eth0, fe80::250:56ff:fe9f:6be7#123 Enabled
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: Listening on interface #4 lo, 127.0.0.1#123 Enabled
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: Listening on interface #5 eth0, 198.108.192.70#123 Enabled
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: kernel time sync status 2040
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 xinetd[1681]: xinetd Version 2.3.14 started with libwrap loadavg labeled-networking options compiled in.
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 xinetd[1681]: Started working: 0 available services
Dec 19 11:53:27 dns1 ntpd[1689]: frequency initialized -1.970 PPM from /var/lib/ntp/drift
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Registered Reporter plugin 'RHTSupport'
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Registered Analyzer plugin 'Python'
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Registered Reporter plugin 'Logger'
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Registered Action plugin 'SOSreport'
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Registered Analyzer plugin 'Kerneloops'
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Registered Action plugin 'KerneloopsScanner'
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Registered Analyzer plugin 'CCpp'
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-auxiliary
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta-2
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-legacy-beta
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-legacy-former
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-legacy-release
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Can't load public GPG key /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-legacy-rhx
Dec 19 11:53:36 dns1 abrtd: Checking for unsaved crashes (dirs to check:7)
Dec 19 11:53:37 dns1 abrtd: Registered Database plugin 'SQLite3'
Dec 19 11:53:37 dns1 abrtd: Done checking for unsaved crashes
Dec 19 11:53:37 dns1 abrtd: Init complete, entering main loop
Dec 19 11:53:46 dns1 abrt[1999]: saved core dump of pid 1998 (/usr/libexec/fprintd) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-1576774426-1998.new/coredump (761856 bytes)
Dec 19 11:53:46 dns1 abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-1576774426-1998' creation detected
Dec 19 11:53:46 dns1 abrtd: Crash is in database already (dup of /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-1361983368-3976)
Dec 19 11:53:46 dns1 abrtd: Deleting crash ccpp-1576774426-1998 (dup of ccpp-1361983368-3976), sending dbus signal
Dec 19 11:53:48 dns1 kernel: type=1305 audit(1576774428.085:19745): audit_enabled=0 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
Dec 19 11:53:48 dns1 kernel: readahead-collector: starting delayed service auditd
Dec 19 11:53:48 dns1 auditd[2018]: Started dispatcher: /sbin/audispd pid: 2020
Dec 19 11:53:48 dns1 audispd: No plugins found, exiting
Dec 19 11:53:48 dns1 auditd[2018]: Init complete, auditd 2.0.4 listening for events (startup state enable)
Dec 19 11:53:48 dns1 kernel: readahead-collector: sorting
Dec 19 11:53:48 dns1 kernel: readahead-collector: finished
Dec 19 11:56:43 dns1 ntpd[1689]: synchronized to 74.6.168.72, stratum 2
Dec 19 11:56:42 dns1 ntpd[1689]: time reset -0.452815 s
Dec 19 11:56:42 dns1 ntpd[1689]: kernel time sync status change 2001
Dec 19 12:02:45 dns1 ntpd[1689]: synchronized to 74.6.168.72, stratum 2
Dec 20 19:40:01 dns1 auditd[2018]: Audit daemon rotating log files
Dec 22 03:50:01 dns1 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.2" x-pid="1337" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed, type 'restart'.
Dec 22 03:50:01 dns1 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
```

Comment: Check **bind**'s logs, maybe it died.

Comment: Well just tried that but the log doesn't go back far enough at this point. The change was made before the 25 and once we realized that nothing was working we changed the spf record back the way it was. Thanks

Comment: Correction I do have all logs I'm looking them over now. One message that starts occurring periodically after we made the initial change:   failed to connect: connection refused. I don't see this error in the records AFTER we reverted the SPF entry back to what it was originally. Could this indicate that the Named file was not working because the service wasn't restarted?

Comment: Can you add those log entries to the question?

Comment: Dec 19 12:09:25 dns2 named[8524]: zone Domaine-name.edu/IN: refresh: retry limit for master 198.XXX.XXX.XXX#53 exceeded (source 0.0.0.0#0)
Dec 19 12:09:25 dns2 named[8524]: zone Domain-name.edu/IN: Transfer started.
Dec 19 12:09:25 dns2 named[8524]: transfer of 'Domain-name.edu/IN' from 198.XXX.XXX.XXX#53: failed to connect: connection refused
Dec 19 12:09:25 dns2 named[8524]: transfer of 'Domain-name.edu/IN' from 198.XXX.XXX.XXX#53: Transfer completed: 0 messages, 0 records, 0 bytes, 0.001 secs (0 bytes/sec)

Comment: I've replaced domain with "Domain-name" and our IP's with XXX.

Comment: Just to reiterate I'm thinking that it's becuase I didn't run this series of commands after making the change: service named status
service named stop
service named start
service named restart

Comment: Is `dns2` a master DNS server? These log lines are from a slave server.

Comment: No 'DNS2' is the Slave. I will check the same records on 'DNS1' now.

Comment: Add the logs editing the question, not in comments.

Comment: The logs you appended show the shutdown sequence of `dns1`. When it was brought up `named` didn't start.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense because there are no more logs until the 26th when my co-worker restarted it again. Could it be just because I didn't manually stop and restart the named service after editing the file?